# Remove Multiplicative Constant from Hypergeometric Function

Tags: transformation, hypergeometric-function

I have a function of the form

$$f(x;\lambda) = {}_2F_1\left(a,b;c;-\frac{e^{2x}}{\lambda}\right)$$

I need to invert this function to solve for the constant $\lambda = f\left(x\right)$.  I could do this numerically using the Newton-Raphson or bisection methods but this is not efficient for me.  There are so many hypergeometric transformations that I don't know where to start.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757329/hypergeometric-function-simple-identity?rq=1

Comment: A good suggestion, but this does not remove $\lambda$ from the hypergeometric term.  It produces $f\sim {}_2F_1(a,b;c;\frac{1}{1+\lambda e^{-2x}})$

Comment: true. Well, this is all else i could find on transformations:http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8

Comment: or this http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.12

Comment: I don't understand: you have the characteristic curve $$e^{ln(\lambda)-2x} $$ which gives an implicit constraint.    You say $$\lambda$$ is a constant and is a function f(x) ?

Comment: I was not able to solve this without using the bisection method.  The goal was to produce a value $\lambda$ given the left hand side, which I call $f(x;\lambda)$, and the coordinate $x$.

Comment: You might try the Lagrange inversion formula to get a symbolic answer about a known value. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem
Setting $ z=e^{2x}/\lambda $
Inverting with respect to z and then solving for $\lambda$
Undoubtedly messy but doable with computers.